# Angular 6 reactive forms select component not selecting the option from patchValue

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on wrapping a select element as a component (called `select-ddl`) with additional functionality.  I didn't get around to the "additional functionality" before I discovered that the correct option isn't being selected automatically by the FormGroup when calling setValue or patchValue.

What really doesn't make sense to me is that validation is working, and if I select a value in the drop-down, calling `this.form.value` returns the right result with `companyId` set.  I believe that means the `SelectControlValueAccessor` is being correctly setup by Angular to wire up the FormControl to the DOM element.

**person-edit.component.ts contains:**

```
id = 0;
form: FormGroup;
record: PersonViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
companies: NameViewModel[] | undefined;

constructor(
  private dataService: PeopleService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({ companyId: [null, [Validators.required]] });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    this.id = Number(params.id)
    this.dataService.getRecord(this.id).subscribe(result => {
        this.record = result;
        this.form.patchValue(this.record);
      });
  this.dataService.getCompanies().subscribe(result => this.companies = result);
}
```

**person-edit.component.html contains:**

```
<select select-ddl id="companyIdInput" formControlName="companyId" [items]="companies"></select>
```

**select-ddl.component.html contains:**

```
@Component({
  selector: "select[select-ddl]",
  template: `<option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>`,
})
export class SelectDdlComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() items: NameViewModel[] | undefined;
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that the companies list loads after the record.  So the options are being created after patchValue was already called on the form.  This wasn't a problem when it was just a normal select in the person-edit.component, but now that I'm using the new `select-ddl`, it's broken.  Also, if I force the companies to load before the record, the problem goes away.

I tried calling `this.form.get("companyId")!.setValue(this.record.companyId)` inside the `getCompanies().subscribe` statement, after this.companies is set.  It didn't help.  However, at that time, the option elements haven't been asynchronously created, so I expected that.

I can work around the problem by passing `this.record.companyId` as an input to the select-ddl, and then putting this on the option element: `[attr.selected]="item.id === itemId ? '' : null"`.  But that's a hack, and I want it to work correctly using the built-in, under-the-hood tooling seemlessly.

**UPDATE**: I'm reasonably sure the problem has something to do with the [NgSelectOption](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts) directive, which seems to bind the options to the select to solve exactly this need.  However, I have no idea (a) how to diagnose why it wouldn't be working in this instance, or (b) how to get it working as it's designed to.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue! Did you solved?

Comment: @NadG I'm sorry... re-reading this now it feels so long ago I barely remember what I was working on.  I believe I abandoned any attempt to put an attribute selector on any of my inputs; it took a fair bit of restructuring, but I'm happy with the result.  If you find a way that works for you, please be sure to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered.  Sorry I'm not any more help.